# Circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, circulant-matrices

$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
B & C\\
C & B
\end{array}
\right)$

Here $A$ is the block circulant matrix and B and  C are $n \times n$ matrices which are circulant.

How can write it as in roots of unity.

How to find the eigenvalues of $A$. Please explain.

Comment: Add a dollar sign before "A=" and after "\right)"

Comment: Thank you Sir. I have modified.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix):

Let $\omega_j = \exp(\frac{2\pi ij}n)$ be the $n$-th roots of unity. Then the vectors
$$
v_j = \frac1{\sqrt n} (1,\ \omega_j, \dots, \omega_j^{n-1})^T
$$
are eigenvectors of $B$ and $C$ to eigenvalues $\lambda_j^B$ and $\lambda_j^C$, respectively. 
Set 
$$
Q= (v_1 \dots v_n) \in\mathbb C^{n,n}.
$$ 
Then $Q$ diagonalizes $B$ and $C$ simultaneously, and it holds
$$
\begin{pmatrix} Q^H&0\\0&Q^H\end{pmatrix}
A
\begin{pmatrix} Q&0\\0&Q\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} D_B&D_C\\D_C&D_B\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $D_B$ and $D_C$ are diagonal matrices with the eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$ on the diagonal.
It follows that the eigenvalues of $A$ are given as the eigenvalues of $2\times 2$ matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_j^B & \lambda_j^C\\
\lambda_j^C & \lambda_j^B
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which are $\lambda_j^B \pm  \lambda_j^C$
with corresponding eigenvectors
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
v_j \\ \pm  v_j\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake.